Scene downloaded from addressable has pink sprite
I have multiple scenes each can be downloaded from addressable. If a scene is completed downloaded , loading scene has no issue, however any of the scene download is on progress  ,other downloaded scene has pink sprite.
Here the code that downloads the scene.
public class AddreasableSceneThumbnail : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string sceneAddress;
    [SerializeField] Transform downloadProgressUI;
    bool isDownloadStarted;
    bool isDownloaded;
    IEnumerator downloadCour;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CheckDownload());
    }
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(downloadCour != null)
            StopCoroutine(downloadCour);
        if (downloadHandlerCheck.IsValid())
        {
            Addressables.Release(downloadHandlerCheck);
        }
        if (downloadHandlerDownload.IsValid())
        {
            Addressables.Release(downloadHandlerDownload); 
        }
    }
    AsyncOperationHandle<long> downloadHandlerCheck;
    IEnumerator CheckDownload()
    {
        downloadHandlerCheck = Addressables.GetDownloadSizeAsync(sceneAddress);

        while (!downloadHandlerCheck.IsDone && downloadHandlerCheck.Status !=AsyncOperationStatus.Failed)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        if (downloadHandlerCheck.Result == 0)
        {
            ActivateButton();
            isDownloaded = true;
        }
        Addressables.Release(downloadHandlerCheck);
    }
    public void OnThumbNailClicked()
    {
        if(isDownloaded)
            Addressables.LoadSceneAsync(sceneAddress,LoadSceneMode.Single);
        if (isDownloadStarted) return;
        isDownloadStarted = true;
        downloadCour= DownloadScene();
        StartCoroutine(downloadCour);
    }
    AsyncOperationHandle downloadHandlerDownload;
    IEnumerator DownloadScene()
    {
        downloadProgressUI.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        downloadProgressUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        downloadHandlerDownload = Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(sceneAddress);
        while (!downloadHandlerDownload.IsDone)
        {
            downloadProgressUI.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1 - downloadHandlerDownload.PercentComplete, 1);
            yield return null;
        }
        isDownloaded = true;
        ActivateButton();
        Addressables.Release(downloadHandlerDownload); //this is culprit

    }
    public void ActivateButton()
    {
        downloadProgressUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

I think there is some issue with builtin shader not being loaded on addreasable, however i could not find any solution to it. The issue is on android build.
Note: Issue occurs when i release the handle, however not releasing handle doesnot load the scene into memory.

pink usually means shader not working

@BugFinder or simply missing
